# jQuery building of array not working from within first function being executed

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, function, jplayer

The following issue is driving me nuts. I've tried all kinds of ways of solving it but I get nothing.

The code is as follows

```
var item = [];
function runCSStweaks() {
    var m=0;
    $('.jp-playlist li').each(function() {
        m++;
        var min1 = -1;
        var max1 = 1;
        var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max1 - min1 + 1)) + min1;
        item[m] = random1;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+random1+'deg)')
    });
};
function actOnSongChange() {
    var m=0;
    $('.jp-playlist li').each(function() {
        m++;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+item[m]+'deg)')
               .css('-webkit-transform','scale(1)')
    });
    var min3 = -1;
    var max3 = 1;
    var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max3 - min3 + 1)) + min3;
    $('.jp-playlist .jp-playlist-current').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+random3+'deg)')
                                          .css('-webkit-transform','scale(1.05)')
});
```

I'll walk you guys through it. Basically, I'm building a playlist using jPlayer. I've set it up so that, when jPlayer finished building the list, the `runCSStweaks()` code will be called in order to apply some small random CSS rotation to each item. (This was an earlier problem I had; could not get these CSS tweaks to be applied once the list was all done; so I had to solve it by placing the call to this variable at the end of the jPlayer list-building process.) Up to here, it works perfectly. All the items are randomly rotated as expected.

Then, the idea is that, as each song finishes playing and goes on to the next, the second script, `actOnSongChange()`, is to be called. This script basically should apply another random rotation and a CSS scale to the current item playing, while returning all previously played items to their original scale.

It seemed as if it would be pretty straightforward but I encountered the issue that I couldn't just set the CSS scale back to 1 without this resetting the original CSS rotation. I guess this is because they both work through CSS transform. So the only solution that comes to mind is to "save" all original rotations in order to call them back as well when the scale is brought back to 1.

In order to do this, I'm creating an array of each random rotation amount when the first script is run and calling each individual array entry back inside the second script.

Here is were I've hit a wall. I've tried everything and have come to the conclusion that the first script does not build the array at all. If I place a `console.log()` in the second script and call for `item` to have it dump the array's contents I get an empty array. If I try to place a `console.log()` within the first script to see what is going on it doesn't even print out. For this same reason, I was forced to place the `var item = []` line outside of the `runCSStweaks()` (otherwise, I got this error through `console.log(item)`: "Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined ").

So, what is apparently obvious, this first function, `runCSStweaks()`, does the CSS tweaks alright, but that's about it. Anything else I place inside is not run and I don't know why.

Am I perhaps missing something? Is there an error in my coding somewhere? Or does it have to do with the order in which jQuery calls and executes things?

I'll continue trying to get through this code in the morning. But for now, my brain is about to build itself a bonfire.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce this problem to something smaller? For example I see some "magic numbers" (min1, max1, min3, max3) which don't have their value changed ever, yet they participate in some css animations which clearly do not relate to your problem.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, calling `runCSStweaks()` from inside the success handler of an ajax function.  Also, do you realize that `item[0]` will always be undefined because the first item you add is `item[1]`.  Makes me wonder why you don't just use `item.push()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had thought of using `push()`. Initially I thought it would be easier to give the array keys in order to call them specifically during function No 2. Of course, I could do similar by using a `for()` loop. However, still the issue is that function No 1 won't create the array. Even if I use `push()`. I did try it at some point. And, about calling in from, inside an Ajax function, the answer is no (just for future info, would this call not work or not properly if made from within an Ajax function?). Thanks for the interest and commment!

Comment: @cherouvim I agree the functions need a little cleaning up. Bear in mind I've been moving stuff around, doing and undoing for hours in order to fix the issue. In the end, they'll deserve some cleaning up. However, I have tried simplifying in order to test it out. I cleared everything from the functions and tried just creating the array in the `each()` call with a fixed string ("hey") and, then, creating a `console.log()`, and nothing more, in the second function. However, the same issue remains: the first function will not create the array; it won't even define the item var if placed inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the basic issue here was **why the first function, `runCSStweaks()`, wasn't creating the array if it was executing the CSS tweaks just fine?**

And the answer, much to my embarrassment, and oh don't I feel the grand fool right now, is very simple:

**I wasn't ever calling function `runCSStweaks()`!**

Initially, I had placed a call to the `runCSStweaks()` right where the jPlayer JS finishes building the playlist and deploys it. As I said in my question's description above, I had been working on this very late at night and, for some strange, mysterious reason, at some point my failing brain had decided to insert the function itself into the jPlayer JS, rather than just calling it from there. (I can only guess the original call wasn't going as planned.)

So, having never erased the original `runCSStweaks()` function, no doubt because I thought I might have to return to calling it in order to keep the original JS tidy, I eventually forgot that I had placed the entire function in there. So, to sum up, the `runCSStweaks()` function wasn't being called, the function that tweaked the CSS was hidden in the original JS, and I was foolishly adding the array builder and etc. in the `runCSStweaks()` and asking myself *Why, oh why, is this not working?!*

So, sorry for that. But thank you guys very much for your help! I think we might have been trying to find the problem here forever but to no avail, as there was no problem; at least not with the function but with my clumsiness. I must say, though, that in your answers and comments I have at least learned two or three very important pieces of info that will prevent me from making other mistakes in the future and posting them here! So thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply Scaling + Rotating to the same element.

that just not how CSS3 works.
try to apply on two different elements. one for scaling, and the other one for rotating.

Hope it helps

**Edit:**

This **can be done in  the same element.**
im sorry.

but.

if you do:

**CSS**

```
/*  WRONG!!  */
span {
-webkit-transform: sacle(1.05);
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

it is clearly that the rotation will override the scaling.
what you should do is:

**JS:**

```
.css('-webkit-transform','scale('+randomScaling+') rotate('+randomRotation+')');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, JohnnyJS. This is good info to know. The only issue is that I still have the problem with having to reapply the same rotation when I modify the scaling. When I try to do this, because the array holding that info is no being created during the first function, I can only either apply the scaling alone and lose the original rotation (as you very well state here) or I have to add the scaling together with an entire newly generated rotation, which I wouldn't like to HAVE to do. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see what exactly you're doing wrong with your `runCSStweaks()` function because we can't see your HTML or how you're calling it.  You can see in [my working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kk2U9/) that the code works fine and populates the `item` array just fine when nothing else is wrong:

```
var item = [];

function runCSStweaks() {
    $('.jp-playlist li').each(function() {
        var min = -90;
        var max = 90;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        item.push(random);
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+ random +'deg)')
    });
};

runCSStweaks();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kk2U9/ that shows the `item` array fully populated with random numbers.

I've exaggerated the rotation just for visual clarify.  The possibilities in your own code/HTML I can think of are:

1. The selector `'.jp-playlist li'` isn't matching anything because that isn't the right selector for your HTML.
2. You're calling this code before the page has been loaded so `.jp-playlist` isn't found.
3. You're calling this code before the `.jp-playlist` and `li` elements have been created (if they are created in code or loaded dynamically after page load).
4. You're getting confused because there's no `item[0]` element in your code that way you are populating that array (that's why I used `.push()` in my code).
5. You aren't calling `runCSStweaks()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! And thanks for taking the time to run a jsFiddle demo on it. As you proved, it works perfectly... the problem was, well, me... as you'll read in my answer... Sorry for that. But thanks a million!